# Where do the traces come from in Casimir's trick?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, s-matrix-theory, trace, matrix-elements

I am following the derivation for electron-muon scattering amplitude in Griffiths textbook and got to the section where they use [Casimir's trick](https://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/CasimirTrick.html). I can't see where the traces come from. Equation 7.123 on pg. 251:

$$\require{cancel} \sum_{i,j =1}^{4} Q_{ij}(\cancel{p}_a + m_a)_{ji} = \sum_{i=1}^{4} [Q(\cancel{p}_a + m_a)]_{ii} = Tr[Q(\cancel{p}_a + m_a)] \tag{7.123}$$

$Q$ is a $4 \times4$ matrix. What I don't understand is the middle step - why is there suddenly only summation of $ii$?

When I write it out I get:

$$\sum_{i,j =1}^{4} Q_{ij}(\cancel{p}_a + m_a)_{ji} = \sum_{i=1}^{4}[Q_{i1}X_{1i} + Q_{i2}X_{2i} + Q_{i3}X_{3i} +  Q_{i4}X_{4i}] $$

Where I've replaced the $4 \times 4$ matrix $\cancel{p}_a - m_a$ with $X$.

Then when I carry the sum out over $i$ I get a load of cross-terms as well as the diagonals, so not sure how that results in a trace, unless Q and X are such that all the diagonal elements equal zero.

Am I doing sums wrong? I'd expect just to be left with the sum of the diagonals.

Comment: $\text{Tr}(AB)=A_{ij}B_{ji}$

Comment: Hint: $\sum_i [AB]_{ii} \ne \sum_i A_{ii}B_{ii}$

Comment: @NiharKarve so this is because you multiply the matrices first inside the square bracket and then find the iith element?

Comment: Exactly. Take it in two steps. First $\sum_{j}A_{ij}B_{jk}=C_{ik}$, and then do $\sum_{i}C_{ii}$.

Comment: @joigus phew, that solved it for me. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trace of any matrix is defined by the sum of its diagonal elements, as was pointed out in the comments.

You can basically view what you have inside your square brackets in Eq. (7.123) as *one* matrix, and then you sum over the diagonals because you only consider the $ii$-elements of the matrix, no mixed terms of the form $ij$ or $ji$, where $i\ne j$.